# SQL Select rows skipping duplicates with former row

Tags: sql, sorting

Quite a noob to SQL but here goes my problem.

Trying to create a query that returns a tv menu, containing time and title, not a problem, however... If there is a Title that are played back to back I would only want to present the first title and starttime.

The result of my current query looks something like this:

```
Time   Title
07.00  Program A
07.45  Program B
08.30  Program C
09.00  Program C
10.00  Program D
11.00  Program A
12.00  Program C
12.30  Program E
```

My desired result is:

```
Time   Title
07.00  Program A
07.45  Program B
08.30  Program C
10.00  Program D
11.00  Program A
12.00  Program C
12.30  Program E
```

I.E filter out duplicates only if they occur after one another.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What is datatype of `Time` column in your output query? If it's of comparable type then you could easily use `SELECT MIN(time_col), title FROM (your_select_query_or_table) GROUP BY title;`

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Server and the TIME column actually originates from a DateTime column.

Answer (score 0):

First this would required ordering column that could represent your data ordering if so then use instead of `TIME` Column.

For instance i have used `Time`

```
select *  
from(select *, 
            (select title 
             from table
             where time < t.time
             order by time desc
             limit 1) Prevtitle
     from table t
    ) tt
where (Prevtitle is null) or 
      (Prevtitle <> title);
```

However, some *DBMS* has no `LIMIT` clause support such as SQL Server if so, use `TOP` clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily done using window functions:

```
select time, title
from (
   select time, title, 
          row_number() over (partition by title order by time) as rn
   from the_table
) t 
where rn = 1
order by time, title;
```

The above is ANSI standard SQL and supported by all modern DBMS.

`order by time` results in picking the first row based on the time. 
If you want to pick the last one use `order by time desc`

Answer (score -1):

I assume you use MYSQL,

You can [group](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the rows by Title using `GROUP BY`, then use `max()` to retrieve the [greater](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp) Time.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT max(time), title FROM tv_menu GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: That won't work because only if same title is there in adjacent rows need to find the min time

Answer (score -1):

You should use the right tool for the right job.

Trying to solve this directly in your select statement, is IMO to choose not to index your data, and extract it unsorted, and then sort it afterwards using code. Databases are lean, mean sorting machines, if only you use proper indexing.

Vice versa, your problem is not easily solved using SQL, but trivial using code.

Do your usual select, order your selection by time. And then in your code, you can do something like:

```
currentTitle = "";
for (r in rows) {
    if (!currentTitle.equals(r.title)) {
        print r.title;
        currentTitle = r.title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually went with your solution after all, did my select into a dataset, turned it into an xml, applied an xslt to it to get rid of the duplicate preceding siblings and Viola' !  sometimes you get stuck just by trying to use the last thing you're learning right now. Great, thanks!